# How to disable pivot item only when it exists?

Tags: excel, vba

In the following code, the line `.PivotItems("Central Events").Visible = False` will throw an error if such pivot item does not exist, hence I am currently ignoring the error with `On Error Resume Next`:

```
With BA_view_pivots_sheet.PivotTables("Corporate & Investment Banking").PivotFields( _
        "Market")
        On Error Resume Next ' ignore error when projects for Central Events does not exist
            .PivotItems("Central Events").Visible = False
        On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

However, instead of ignoring the error, I would like to implement a check if such pivot item exists and disable it only in such case. So I came up with something like this, but obviously it won't work, because the object is non- existent:

```
With BA_view_pivots_sheet.PivotTables("Corporate & Investment Banking").PivotFields( _
        "Market")
        If Not .PivotItems("Central Events") Is Nothing then
            .PivotItems("Central Events").Visible = False
        End if
End With
```

Is there any other way to get around this possible error, apart from ignoring it like in my first code snippet?

Comment: Why do you want to change it? You would need to loop through all `PivotItems` and compare their name against the string `"Central Events"`. But I think it's much easier to use `On Error Resume Next / Goto` and I see nothing wrong with it (for this case). It's even faster than a loop is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need something like this:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable, pivot_item As PivotItem
For Each pt In BA_view_pivots_sheet.PivotTables
    If pt.Name = "Corporate & Investment Banking" Then 'check that pivot name exists
        For Each pivot_item In pt.PivotFields("Market").PivotItems
            If pivot_item.Name = "Central Events" Then  'check that item name exists
                pivot_item.Visible = False: Exit For
            End If
        Next pivot_item: Exit For
    End If
Next pt
```

Comment: I see no advantage over using `On Error Resume Next / Goto 0` it's probably even slower than before now.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  I not saw the question about `>...what it will be more faster ....error handler or iteration within object ...<`, OP clearly asked `>... instead of ignoring the error, I would like to implement a check if such pivot item exists ...<` and this is the clear answer on requested help.

Comment: Of course your answer is technically correct, totally agree.